# Rails 6 devise_ldap_authenticatable saving duplicate users with different username capitalization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am trying to make it so that **devise_ldap_authenticatable** only creates one record per user, given a username when logging in. The issue I am having, is devise_ldap_authenticatable is saving the same username but with a capital letter. Its becoming troublesome for our users to have duplicate user profiles. I only receive a Completed 302 Found when both records are created with the uppercase/lowercase usernames. How can I create only one record per user, despite the capitalization for Active Directory usernames?

If a user logs in with dwilliams and Dwilliams, a new user should not be created and stored in the database.

## **user.rb**

```
    class User < ApplicationRecord

    devise :ldap_authenticatable...

    before_save :ldap_before_save

    validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: true}
    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :username, use: :slugged

    def ldap_before_save
     self.email = Devise::LDAP::Adapter.get_ldap_param(self.username, "mail").try(:first)
     self.name = Devise::LDAP::Adapter.get_ldap_param(self.username, "name").try(:first)
    end
   end
```

Rails log

```
LDAP: LDAP search for login: sAMAccount=dwilliams
LDAP: search yielded 1 matches
LDAP: Requested param mail has value ["dwilliams@econ.com"]
LDAP: LDAP search login: sAMAccountName=dwilliams
LDAP: LDAP search yielded 1 matches
LDAP: Requested param has value ["David Williams"]
(0.4ms) COMMIT
Redirected to 
Completed 302 Found

.....
LDAP: LDAP search for login: sAMAccount=Dwilliams
LDAP: search yielded 1 matches
LDAP: Authorizing user CN=David Williams, OU....
(0.4ms) BEGIN
User Update...
(1.5ms) COMMIT
```

Answer (score 0):

You should validate `uniqueness` with case insensitive

```
validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

Comment: I get a validation failed error username already exist. It doesn't redirect or anything. Can you please test that one record is created when saving a new user with Active Directory?

Comment: Also, what about config.case_insensitive_keys = [:username]? Should I keep that? Or is it just not working for ldap?

Comment: I had duplicate keys in my devise.rb. That may have been the cause of the issue. I will test it.

Comment: AFAIK ldap dn is case insensitive. So the solution here is setting User model to treat `username` as case insensitive, as my code above. Or you can add a `before_validation` method to downcase username. I personally don't like the idea of downcase all usernames because we need to have a rake task to fix for all existing data.

Comment: I believe that adding config.case_insensitive_keys = [:username] and your recommendation solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

If none is working out then you can also add validation rules to the backend database to avoid duplicating value to the username column. Just my two cents